# Show all branches that commit A is on and commit B is not on?

Tags: git, branch

I have multiple branches and have discovered a commit A that introduced a bug into the system.  This was subsequently fixed by commit B on one of the branches and merged back to master, but at the time it was not cherry-picked to all offending branches.

I was wondering if there is a command that will show all offending branches that have commit A but do not have commit B?

I have been using the following to determine that a commit exists on a branch

```
$ git branch -r --contains=A
```

but I want to try and add to this to include something like

```
$ git branch -r --contains=A ^--contains=B
```

As a side note I have checked and there are no other commits that contain the same change, i.e. it has not been cherry-picked on to any other branches, but some branches have commit B where they have diverged from master since the merge and some don't where they already existed  before commit B was introduced.

Additionally the ability to check for several commits would be useful where the commit that has fixed an issue (commit B in this case) is cherry-picked onto several branches already giving different commit SHA's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
diff <(git branch -r --contains=A) <(git branch -r --contains=B)
```

It is far from perfect but it might help.

Comment: Hi, This looks like it may be very close, as you say it's not perfect.  Could you provide some detail as to what the following does `diff <() <()`

Comment: This link explains what `diff <() <()` does: http://crashingdaily.wordpress.com/2008/03/06/diff-two-stdout-streams/ It might only work with BASH.

Comment: `comm` command (i.e. `comm -23`) should be useful for what you're doing.