# Show branches that do not contain commit

Tags: git, branch, dvcs

`git branch -a --contains <hash>` gives me all those branches containing `hash`. what I want is `git branch -a --no-contains <hash>`. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a command to accomplish this, so I'm thinking the solution is something like:

`git branch -a | grep -v output of(git branch -a --contains)` but my bash isn't up to the task.

[Show all branches that commit A is on and commit B is not on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187302/show-all-branches-that-commit-a-is-on-and-commit-b-is-not-on) would seem to apply, but the approach seems more complicated than necessary.

What is the best/most simple approach to accomplish the above?

Comment: For visibility: **The `--no-contains` flag was added in [Git 2.13](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.13.0/Documentation/RelNotes/2.13.0.txt)**.. As stated in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44687845/1667513).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`grep` has a `-F` option which matches fixed strings. Would be useful for what you're doing.

```
git branch -a | grep -vF "$(git branch -a --contains <hash>)"
```

Unfortunately, `-F` will filter out branches names that have a partial match. As suggested by antak, we can use `comm` instead for a more reliable diff.

```
git branch -a | sort | comm -3 - <(git branch -a --contains <hash> | sort)
```

Comment: Note that this will incorrectly hide branches that partially match names of branches that contains said commit. e.g. `echo -e "aaa\nbbb" | grep -vF "$(echo aa)"`

Comment: @antak Thanks! Good catch!

Answer (score 9):

The `--no-contains` flag was added in [Git 2.13](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.13.0/Documentation/RelNotes/2.13.0.txt).

Answer (score 3):

Since the accepted answer will run afoul if branch names partially match, here's one that handles this situtuation.

```
git branch -a | comm -3 - <(git branch -a --contains <hash>)
```

`| sort` may be added to the end of both commands if the `comm: file 1 is not in sorted order` warning disturbs you.  However, this is not necessary for getting correct results as the ordering of the two inputs are equivalent.